# Serving static files with camel routes

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to serve a static file in camel routes.

The routes in my main class contains this piece of code:

```
public final void configure() throws Exception {
    // declaring camel routes
    // match on uri prefix must be true when parameters are passed as part of the uri
    // for example, "http://localhost/hello/rick"
    // http.port is in local.properties file user-api

    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{http.port}}/user/dist/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
      .process( new StaticProcessor( "help", "index.html", "dist"))
      .routeId( "static");

    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{http.port}}/user?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .to("cxfbean:userService");
  }
```

This works good. When I hit the url: `http://xxxx:8086/user/dist/index.html`, my index page is rendered and the url shows to be`http://xxxx:8086/user/dist/` in url bar.

But when I reload the page (press F5), the url becomes: `http://xxxx:8086/user/dist//` and I get error like:

> This page should have been replaced by Swagger. Do you have the
>   following in your application's pom.xml as the only reference to the
>   swagger-maven-plugin?
>
> ```
>     <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <id>swagger</id>
>                         <phase>compile</phase>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
> ```

I have this dependency in my effective POM. So what am I missing?

I wish to achieve that any url with `http://clv035sl-8947d6:8888/user/dist` should route the call to `index.html`. Why I need to explictly write `index.html` at end of the url?

Any help/ suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried removing the slash bar "/" from the "dist", leaving something like "jetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{http.port}}/user/dist?matchOnUriPrefix=true"? Or maybe swagger is taking place from the route while processing the servlet. Try to remove it to see the results.

Comment: @RicardoZanini , I tried removing the "/" after dist, but this didn't work. :(

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple JUnit Test case to test your scenario based on [this blog post](http://code.notsoclever.cc/writing-camel-component-camel-static-resource/).

Where are the implementation of the `StaticProcessor` class? I've implemented something for this scenario that is quite similar (IMHO):

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/user/dist?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(new Processor() {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Message in = exchange.getIn();

            String relativepath = in.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, String.class);
            String requestPath = in.getHeader("CamelServletContextPath", String.class); //CamelServletContextPath

            if (relativepath.isEmpty() || relativepath.equals("/")) {
                relativepath = "index.html";
            }

            final String formattedPath = String.format("%s/%s", requestPath, relativepath);
            InputStream pathStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(formattedPath);
            Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(this.getClass().getResource(formattedPath).getPath());

            Message out = exchange.getOut();
            try {
                out.setBody(IOUtils.toByteArray(pathStream));
                out.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, Files.probeContentType(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                out.setBody(relativepath + " not found.");
                out.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, "404");
            }
        }
    }).routeId("static");
}
```

It takes from the classpath the resources that needed to be exposed and set the out message to the response. Please, take a look at the entire [test case](https://github.com/ricardozanini/camel-labs/blob/master/src/test/java/com/stackoverflow/camel/labs/JettyServeStaticRouterTest.java).

I've tested the following URLs:

- http://localhost:8080/user/dist/
- http://localhost:8080/user/dist
- http://localhost:8080/user/dist/index.html

Please note that I added the swagger plugin dependency just like you did.

Let me know if that helps or point where the `StaticProcessor` implementation is that I may test with it and edit my answer.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for taking effort in doing this Rnd. But still I am not sure, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi! Maybe the problem resides in `StaticProcessor`. Where's the implementation? Could you handle it to me?

Comment: This really works good. But when I hit url : `http://localhost:8080/user/dist/index.html`, I get name of all js files in console. MY networks tab shows all js files loaded including index.html. But index.html is not served (means the content is not loaded in browser). The browser is blank. Any help?

Comment: Hi! I recommend that you use other solution to serve static files instead of trying to work on your own using Camel. Perhaps Apache Httpd or NGINX. What’s your intention behind this static content? After the static is served, what you need to do?