# How to add regex to Camel routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to add regex to camel routes. But I am really not getting any hint. I am using this route to server a static resource (index.html):

```
from("pjetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{http.port}}/user/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")    
    .process( new StaticProcessor( "/dist/", "index.html", "dist"))
    .routeId( "static");
```

I am able to access the index.html via following urls:

```
http://loccalhost:8080/user/index.html
http://localhost:8080/user/
```

Now I want any url starting with `http://loccalhost:8080/user` to render index page. Like:

```
http://loccalhost:8080/user/abc/index.html
http://localhost:8080/user/test/
http://localhost:8080/user/anyting
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Camel is not a web server btw, so whatever you want to render or return as web response, is whatever you do in that `StaticProcessor` you have coded yourself.

You can get the actual URL that was requested from the Camel Message header, and from that information, you can decide what to render.

Comment: @prashant-prabhakar-singh that's what I was talking about in your other question regarding your web response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406799/serving-static-files-with-camel-routes. The processor I implemented as an example is working like you expected. I think you may having issues with your `StaticProcessor` implementation.